# Display image returned as bytes in a @ResponseBody in Controller

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

In my application I have a Controller which when a form delivers the picture it stores the picture in the needed directory. The name of the picture is the userId. I am using Spring-boot and Thyemeleaf.
The function that stores the image in the directory with the userId works fine. 
Now I have a function that gets this image and returns it as bytes so that I access it from Thymeleaf.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/displayPicture/{userId}")
@ResponseBody
public byte[] getImage(@PathVariable(value = "userId") String userId) throws IOException {
    File serverFile = new File("path");
    return Files.readAllBytes(serverFile.toPath());
}
```

How do I achieve this?
I return the userId from a different controller previously as follows:

```
modelAndView.addObject("userId", user.getUserId());
```

html form:

```html
<form method="POST" th:action="@{/form}"
      enctype="multipart/form-data" role="form">
    <input id="fileUpload" type="file" name="file" onchange="this.form.submit()"/>
    <img th:href="/displayPicture/${userId}"/> // This is what I am asking how to do correctly
</form>
```

I want when the picture to be uploaded and when the modelAndView is returned, it returns and displays the uploaded image.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: did you try modelAndView.addObject("image", byteArray);?

Comment: And then on <img th:href >I should call it like I've done in the code ? So that the img calls the ResponseBody code that returns the bytes ?
Cuz the form where the image is submitted stores the image in the directory.
or do you mean that in the same function where the image is stored, the function should return it? 
I'm sorry, using Spring for the first time.Not quite sure what the best way would be

Comment: can you try **th:href=" '/displayPicture/' + ${userId}"**  ?

Answer (score 0):

A context-relative URL?

```xml
<img th:href="@{/displayPicture/{userId}(userId=${userId})}"/>
```